# How to debug VB6 Automation errors

Tags: debugging, vb6

I work on a big VB6 application and I have many difficulties to resolve some bugs which appear when I close the program.

All these errors appear after the last code line so it is impossible for me to debug. I know that these errors are "AUTOMATION errors". I tried to attach the process in Visual Studio 2010 and I had these errors :
Exception de première chance à 0x7643c41f dans VB6.EXE : 0xC000008F: Floating-point inexact result.

How can I know with the memory pointer in which DLL the error occurs ?

EDIT: more information about WinDbg

```
(166c.2758): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)  
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.  
This exception may be expected and handled.  
eax=01f8b004 ebx=00000800 ecx=01f16ce4 edx=00000000 esi=01f8b004 edi=006d0a68  
eip=729926a6 esp=0018f648 ebp=75850dfb iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc  
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246  
MSVBVM60!IID_IVbaHost+0x24066:  
729926a6 ff7174          push    dword ptr [ecx+74h]  ds:002b:01f16d58=????????
```

Comment: Have you tried VMMap: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx

Comment: No but I know that the program want to access to a memory pointer that no longer exists. I don't want to know what value is in the pointer but what dll try to access to this pointer.

Comment: VMMap will show you where the DLLs are. You may find that 0x7643c41f is in a system DLL though

Comment: When you say "I tried to attach the process in Visual Studio 2010" does that mean you were able OR not able to attach? If you were able to attach, then just look at the thread stack.

Comment: Yes, I am able to attach to the process but I don't have the stack trace because my program is in VB6

Comment: This is the error : unmanaged exception in ....exe : 0xC0000005 : access violation when reading 0x02656d58. I can see that this address is a heap but I don't have the same information when using windbg an VMMap. What can I do with that ?

Answer (score 1):

This part got my attention:

```
"Floating-point inexact result."
```

Try this:

Go to:
Project > Project Properties > Compile > Advanced Optimizations

Check that "Remove Floating Point Error Checks" and "Allow Unrounded Floating Point Operations" boxes are **NOT** ticked. If they are ticked, untick them, save and re-run the project. This allows Visual Basic to check floating point data types and their related expressions for problems, before they can crash the programming environment. Then, you can fix those errors that it finds (like dividing by zero), rather than simply skipping over them, and optionally set the optimizations setting back when you are happy that everything is fixed.

Comment: Do you have any subclassing code in your program? Try temporarily removing it, and seeing if the error(s) still occur.

Comment: No I don't have any subclassing code. Infact, the last error message that I have is in the VB6 virtual machine dll but I don't know how could I see the code line executed by the VB6VM dll. So I can't know if it is an error in this DLL or from our code executed in the dll...